# How to add the retrying times or extend the fetching time?

Tags: bazel

I am installing ClusterFuzz tools,  the command `bazel run xxxx` only could keep 65 seconds, but we can only run these commands via a proxy in my env and looks the network is unstable.
the command: `bazel run --keep_going //local:create_gopath`

the error information: http://paste.openstack.org/show/745193/
Some errors perform "Could not resolve host: github.com", Actually it could be requested in the env, :(

try to clone the repo with git command.

```
git clone https://github.com/pkg/errors /home/fuzz/.cache/bazel/_bazel_fuzz/6dcde86a643777ef5d89aaa636cdd7cd/external/com_github_pkg_errors
Cloning into '/home/fuzz/.cache/bazel/_bazel_fuzz/6dcde86a643777ef5d89aaa636cdd7cd/external/com_github_pkg_errors'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 528, done.
Receiving objects: 100% (528/528), 117.06 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
remote: Total 528 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 528
Resolving deltas: 100% (322/322), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason. Use HTTP(S)_PROXY instead of http(s)_proxy if using proxy in bazel.